# Column and row names missing in a bipartite network web visualization using plotweb() in Rstudio

Tags: bipartite

When I plot my web, which has column and row names, the lables on the visualisation show up as col1 and row 1 etc.

This is despite the fact that ?plotweb states that the defualt is to show full lables:

high.lablength number of characters of upper labels that should be plotted. If zero no labels are shown, default is NULL which plots the complete labels.

and

low.lablength number of characters of lower labels that should be plotted. If zero no labels are shown, default is NULL which plots the complete labels.

Can anyone point me in the direction of where I might have gone wrong?

This is the code I wrote:

cn_dfWEB_summer <- frame2webs(cn_df_summer, varnames = c("Plant", "Pollinator_order", "WebID", "Weight"), type.out = "array", emptylist = FALSE)

plotweb(cn_dfWEB_summer, empty = FALSE)

When I produce the plot, it looks fine, apart from the fact that none of the edges show their proper names. Only col and row numbers. I cannot find an argument that will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had to transform my data frame to an array of integers to solve it.

```
spxvisitOK <- as.matrix(sapply(spxvisit, as.integer))
```

Then add the row names and that's it. (columns names were already loaded on my data)

```
row.names(spxvisitOK)<-c("Abelia sp",
                        "Bougainvillea sp",
                        "Bulbine frutescens")
```

When I compared the properties of my data frame with the test data (safariland), I realized that the package loaded and saw they were slightly different.

I hope you were able to solve it.